# android game - keeping track of time

Tags: android

I have a puzzle game for android. When the puzzle starts I take the current time:

`long startTime = System.currentTimeInMillis()`

When the player completes the puzzle, I take the time again, subtract the starting time and work out the elapsed time. This is all ok.

My problem is what to do when the application is interrupted. For example by a phone call. At the moment, the puzzle remains in it's previous state automatically (as it is in a view). However, the calculation `completionTime = currentTime - startTime` will now be invalid.

I have tried saving the elapsed time using `onSaveInstaceState(Bundle)`. However its counterpart, `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` is not called when re-entering the app. Rather, the `onResume()` method is called instead? I have read this is because the app has not been 'killed', rather it is still in memory. In the case of a 'kill', I'd imagine the state of the View will also be lost? I don't think it's terribly necessary to keep track of the view in this case, so I won't worry about the time either.

Is there a way to read a bundle from onResume(), should I just implement a shared preference?

I'd like to avoid updating the elapsed time in the game loop as this seems inefficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***I would advice not using a SharedPreference at all.***

---

You will only need 2 fields: **`startTime`** and **`elapsedTime`**

When the player starts, initialise **`elapsedTime`** to **`0`** and **`startTime`** to **`System.currentTimeMillis()`**

When `onPause()` is called, initialise **`elapsedTime`** using

```
elapsedTime = elapsedTime + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

When `onResume()` is called, initialise **`startTime`** to **`System.currentTimeMillis()`**

When the player is done, the time is

```
elapsedTime = elapsedTime + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

---

Please, if the logic has a flaw, comment (:

Note: There exists a way to use only **one** field.! But we'll keep that for the reader to discover.

Comment: if system reboots, the variables, will take a hit, i think. so considering the game doesn't get killed or phone is not rebooted, your idea is good. so in those extreme cases, storing time is mandatory.

Comment: if the game is killed everything is gone! AND BUT If you choose to save the state of the game! save these two variables. It is better than SharedPreferences

Comment: yeah, you are right again, as long as game is not saved. but games have a save feature generally, i was thinking in that aspect.

Comment: I haven't added a save feature. I don't think I will bother as most games should only be a few minutes long. I have implemented something similar to what you suggested Sherif, and it appears to work. In `onPause()` I have `elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime` and `onResume` I have `startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsed` . It's not that I think your suggestion wouldn't work - but this way requires less changes in my code elsewhere (Although I am naughty for having a variable startTime which doesn't actually represent the starting time)

Comment: its all about inspiration ... am glad

Answer (score 2):

shared preference seems a better idea to me.

1. calculate the time difference in onPause() , when the game goes to background, assuming user is already playing game. Add this difference to the previous time in the shared preference and store it again.
2. start the clock again on onResume() and repeat step 1 if necessary.

I hope you get the idea.