# how to Calculate the screen on time of android device

Tags: java, android, do-while

I am building an application that can calculate the screen on time of a day.
This is my implementation i can't figure out what could be the part in do-while loop

```
PowerManager powerManager=(PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn= powerManager.isScreenOn();
do{

}while(isScreenOn);
```

Comment: BTW...You spelt android wrong - you spelt it andriod. And can you clarify your question.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate how long the screen has been on?

Comment: Yes .The screen has been on a day @Nathan Tuggy

Answer (score 3):

You can use a modified version of this answer to keep time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8154095/4380308

*Modified Version:*

---

You will only need 2 fields: **`startTime`** and **`elapsedTime`**

When you want to start recording time, initialise **`elapsedTime`** to **`0`** and **`startTime`** to **`System.currentTimeMillis()`**

When `onPause()` is called, initialise **`elapsedTime`** using

```
elapsedTime = elapsedTime + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

When `onResume()` is called, initialise **`startTime`** to **`System.currentTimeMillis()`**

When you're done recording time, the time is

```
elapsedTime = elapsedTime + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

---

Besides `onPause()` and `onResume()` you may wish to re-initialize **`startTime`** when **`isScreenOn`** is false and the loop is broken until **`isScreenOn`** is true again, or whatever implementation you decide to use to determine when to and not to record time.